# Execute something BEFORE login (Jessie)

Tags: boot, raspbian-jessie

I tried many things to execute something PRIOR (before) to any login, but none of them worked in any of the mentioned configurations:

- rc.local
- .bashrc
- init.d tab
- systemd
- crontab (detailed here: https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/)

I have Raspbian Jessie: Linux raspberrypi 4.9.14-v7+ #977 SMP Mon Mar 13 18:25:19 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

BTW: I tried also raspi-config with default login and password but it didn't work neither. I need the execution of a py program when the raspi boots without any login from myself.

Any idea? Thanks!

Kind regards, Francisco

Comment: Most of those should have worked.  Could you explain in your question what went wrong with the crontab attempt?  What did you do in detail?

Comment: Hi thanks! 

I tried again the cron thing and it worked! I followed actually my own link and checked again: https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/auto-run-python-programs-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would think that crontab with @reboot would have worked. Here is a [nice step by step on how to Launch a Python script on startup](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/?ALLSTEPS).  Please try to see if that works.